# Start and Stopping a dynamic grid of audio src's based on their start and stop times?

Tags: javascript

right now I have a dynamic list of audio files that I can play and pause them as I please, but each one has a specific start and stop time I want them to only play until.

This just loops through each of my play buttons assigning the playAudio function to the click event

```
var playBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("playBtn");

for (var i = 0; i < playBtns.length; i++){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio" + playBtns[i].id);

    playBtns[i].onclick = function(){
        playAudio(this.id);
    }
}
```

So with this I can play the audio, pause, and play other audio and it will pause any other audio being played and resting it back to its start position.

```
function playAudio(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio" + id);
    var playbtn = document.getElementById(id);
    var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    var playBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("playBtn");

    if(audio.paused){
        for(i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++){ 
            if("audio" + id != sounds[i].id){
                var start = convertToSeconds(sounds[i].dataset.start);
                sounds[i].currentTime = start;
                sounds[i].pause(); 
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < playBtns.length; i++){
            playBtns[i].innerHTML = "<img src=\"/images/play_button.png\">";
        }

        audio.play();
        playbtn.innerHTML = "<img src=\"/images/pause_button.png\">";

    } else {

        audio.pause();
        playbtn.innerHTML = "<img src=\"/images/play_button.png\">";

    }
}
```

I made a function to stop the audio if it gets to the stop time

```
function stopAudio(startTime, stopTime){
        var newTime = convertToSeconds(stopTime);
        console.log(audio.currentTime);
        if(audio.currentTime >= stopTime){
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = startTime;
        }
}
```

and if I add to my playBtn loop the stopAudio function it only works for the latest audio file any previous audio files just play through the whole duration

```
for (var i = 0; i < playBtns.length; i++){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio" + playBtns[i].id);
    var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    var start = convertToSeconds(sounds[i].dataset.start);
    var stop = convertToSeconds(sounds[i].dataset.stop);

    audio.ontimeupdate = function(){ stopAudio(start, stop) };

    playBtns[i].onclick = function(){
        playAudio(this.id);
    }
}
```

Any help on solving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any advice.